# Will subquery (using IN) run multiple times for update statement (SQL Server 2017)

Tags: sql-server, update, sql-server-2017, subquery

Where an update statement is updating the value returned by a subquery - will the subquery be run for each row?

```
UPDATE a 
SET DM = 1
FROM TableA a 
WHERE a.ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TableA WHERE DM = 1)
```

Column ID is not unique in the table so we can have multiple rows for an ID

Will it always update all rows for the ID to DM = 1 or sometime just one?

Comment: Why not use `UPDATE ... WHERE DM <> 1`?

Comment: I want to update only where there are none for the ID already set to 1. There are multiple rows for that ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will it always update all rows for the ID to DM = 1 or sometime just
>   one?

If you don't have `NULL` values in the `ID` column then either all `DM`'s for one type of `ID != 1` and as a result all `ID`'s that have the same value will be updated or none.

But as said previously, depending on nullability of the `ID` column you can have suprising results and performance implications.

More on `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

An example of spools being added & multiple table accesses as a result of using `NOT IN`

[image]

A cleaner way to write your query:

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.DM = 1
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT ID FROM TableA  b
WHERE b.DM = 1
AND b.ID = a.id );
```

Do note that `NULL` values will be updated as well, you would have to add extra logic such as adding `AND a.id IS NOT NULL;`.

Resulting cleaner join path:

[image]

**Example of null values resulting in 0 updates happening:**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA (id int,DM int);

INSERT INTO dbo.TableA(id,DM)

SELECT TOP 500 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) %200, 1
FROM MASTER..spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY MASTER..spt_values spt2;

INSERT INTO dbo.TableA(id,DM)

SELECT TOP 500 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) +200  , 0
FROM MASTER..spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY MASTER..spt_values spt2;

INSERT INTO dbo.TableA(id,DM)
VALUES(NULL,1),(NULL,0);

UPDATE a 
SET DM = 1
FROM TableA a 
WHERE a.ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TableA WHERE DM = 1) ;
```

*--> 0 rows affected*

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.DM = 1
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT ID FROM TableA  b
WHERE b.DM = 1
AND b.ID = a.id )
AND a.id IS NOT NULL; --If you do not want to update null id's
```

*--> (500 rows affected)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer and interesting info re NULL values using IN. Was just curious if there would ever be a case where the subquery would be run for each row (from your post I assume not)

Comment: @Dale - When the anti semi join uses nested loops then part of the subquery would run for each row